# Buddhism Community

Tags: doubt

What type of community normally in a country to feedback on the Buddhism Study in the country or Buddhism Temple for improvement ? Sangha Community? Some Temple claimed they the HQ or Main branch ? How to identify the right place?

I.e. if a temple selling talisman which is disallowed as I understand then where do I feedback normally ?

Answer (score 1):

> When looking for a teacher, you want someone who will evaluate your actions as a work in progress, and you have to apply the same standard to him or her. And you’re not trying to take on the superhuman role of evaluating that person’s essential worth. You’re simply judging whether his or her actions embody the kinds of skills you’d like to develop and the types of mental qualities—which are also a kind of action—that you’d trust in a trainer or guide. - Thanissaro Bhikku [The Power of Judgement](https://tricycle.org/magazine/power-judgment/)

You must go to a temple and see if the views align with yours. You must evaluate if you would like to be like these people. This is the best way to evaluate a temple.

A secondary question is: How do I choose a path? For this, you must also study and see if the views make sense to you. Test them. If path X says Y works, then what happens if you don't do Y. Does it lead you closer or further from inner peace?

It is a long path to find what works for you, but it is worth the effort. If anything is worth effort, it is the path to inner peace.

Edit:

I think that I may have misunderstood the specifics of your question. You may be able to talk to the Abbott about your worries. If that does not remedy your situation, then you may not fit in with that sangha or may want to reconsider your relationship there.

The trouble is that some monasteries do not work in accordance with the dhamma-vinaya. You cannot stop it -- you cannot make people live in accordance with the Dhamma. In my opinion, all you can do is choose whether or not you want to continue to practice there.

Comment: well, the main intention I ask the question is the example I given above.. I have edited my question

Comment: Hi Wayne,

I have edited my post to reflect your edit. Sorry for any confusion. 

I hope that all works out for you and you may continue to have a sangha to practice with

Comment: you cannot make people live in accordance with the Dhamma. --》 that is correct but some other religion just commented the zero knowledge Buddhist (when u pick up anyone in South China and ask who is Buddha then they normally cannot answer) as communist mindset or no religion/no education people. Some politician make use of this to create hatred that impacting my daily lifestyle or simply it's discrimination coming from no where

Comment: Hi Wayne, I'm having trouble understanding exactly what you're trying to say. Regardless, I'm sorry that you have to deal with any discrimination. It is painful. All we can do is try to practice the Dhamma. Suffering is a result of how we speak to ourselves and how we experience reality. Peoples actions may exacerbate it, but we may realize the reality of suffering. May you be safe, happy, and swiftly realize peace

Comment: you cannot make people live in accordance with the Dhamma. --》1. Many Buddhist as recorded in their National ID card has almost zero knowledge in Buddhism especially in South China and South East Asia. 2. Worshiping without a guide at temple (Almost all folks especially in those Temple that too commercialize in City Centre), fortune telling at temple and Being Superstitious 3.Many non Buddhist would identified this as communist mindset (no religion race) and the below dangerous stuff was created, just to name a few - youtube.com/watch?v=3GB3qsFT0xQ

Comment: one of the reason that created the huge damages is all Religion Study was banned for about 20 years during 1st communist lead, the premier Mao after Opium War and World War fight for a century++. Only last 10 years, there is a significant improvement on Civilization, restoration of Philosophy and Religion study. cfr.org/backgrounder/chinas-big-bet-soft-power. But this only applicable to China, outside of it still having big issue and i can sense discrimination still heavy. Hope this explained what i mentioned earlier.

Comment: as a conclusion, i disagreed the view/discrimination from non Buddhist to Buddhist as a follower of Satan alike that has 0 knowledge on Buddhism. So, when i m free then i would like to write an online research paper with suggested improvement action and get the proper channel like Sangha or Buddhism community to review.

Comment: Those people just don't know or don't understand what is Buddhism is innocent sentient and not follower of Satan. I believe no matter how good is my online writing, discrimination still exist but hopefully help "a little". One of the example as below https://erlc.com/resource-library/articles/4-ways-christians-can-respond-to-a-satanic-statue

Comment: I think the edit to my question answers what you're speaking about. We can only live in accordance with the true Dhamma. Such a misrepresentation of the Dhamma has shown up in Thailand (and everywhere else throughout history), and led to the creation of the wilderness or Kammathana tradition. The Dhamma is ~necessarily~ counter culture and so there will always be these problems. Practice in accordance with the Dhamma and profess the true Dhamma